# "like every morning" x "as every morning"... are both correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context

She was going to school 'like' every morning when her mother called her on the phone.

She was going to school 'as' every morning when her mother called her on the phone.

Are both correct to indicate habit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these sound awkward to my ear, and the use of "like" sounds both awkward and uneducated. I would favor one of

> - She was going to school, as she did every morning, when her mother called her on the phone.
> - She was going to school, as she usually did in the morning, when her mother called her on the phone.
> - She was going to school, just like every morning, when her mother called her on the phone.

But I can't formulate any "rule" for this preference, and it may be no more than a preference.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused: "She was going to school 'like' every morning when her mother called her on the phone." sounds awkward (*and* uneducated), but "She was going to school, just like every morning, when her mother called her on the phone." is OK? Is the the "just"? or the commas?

Comment: @ Lorel C.  I admit this is an opinion, and I don't have a source to cite, an it may not be how others would see it. The use of "like" evokes the "like vs as" distinction, to me, while the "just like" construction seems much more natural. Perhaps I'm weird here.